# Error handling Karate -- jbang.exec() (Node-npm)

Tags: javascript, npm, karate

I have a question here, that we are presenting in our project.

We need to be able to control when **KARATE** gives an **OK** or a **KO**, right now this function always returns `0` regardless of whether a test fails or not..

[KARATE OUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV4HX.png)

This is a function:

```
karate.executable = function () {
    let prefix = karate.config.dir ? '-Dkarate.config.dir=' + karate.config.dir + ' '  : '';
    return prefix + 'com.intuit.karate:karate-core:' + karate.version + ':all';
};
karate.exec = function (args) {
    if (!args) {
        var args = process.argv.slice(2).join(' ');
        console.log("ARGUMENT " + args)
    }
    process.env['KARATE_META'] = 'npm:' + process.env.npm_package_version;
    var error = jbang.exec(karate.executable() + ' ' + args);
    console.log("OUT " + error)
};
module.exports = karate;
```

I tried modifying the function, but it generates errors

I expect karate.exec to return a 1 if the test fails and a 0 if everything goes OK

Answer (score 0):

You can [open an issue](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-npm), but it would be great to get some contributions to fix this. I think the [jbang NPM](https://github.com/jbangdev/jbang-npm) code needs to be changed also.

If you have people good at node in your team see if you can contribute. Karate started as a Java project, so most teams use the binary executable after installing a JRE. We are looking to improve the Karate NPM module so that it does not depend on jbang, but it will take some time. In the meantime I recommend that you try to use [Karate directly](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#standalone-jar) and it should be easy to create a Docker container, since your question seems focused on running a CI build.